# Adding price groups by sku and the fastest way possible

Tags: magento-1.9, price-rules

**UPDATE**

My Magento installation was not happy with me trying out all kinds of stuff, so I restarted the server and I got this to work.

```
$groupProperties[] = [
    'website_id' => '0',
    'cust_group' => $group->getId(),
    'price' => $itemPrice
];

$product->setGroupPrice($groupProperties);
$product->save();
```

I will test later if the answer provided by Paj has a performance gain.

**Original post**

I have now searched the whole internet thin and I'm about to go crazy. I can not seem to find any good documentation (please link if you know any good sites)

I have an array with custom price group names, the prices for the user added to this price group and a SKU for finding the product in Magento.

I should probably say, that it's an import from Microsoft Navision, so I don't have the id of the product available, only the SKU.

**The array structure:**

```
$prices[$sku][$customGroupName] = $priceForOneItem;

Ex.: $prices['T5329786']['NAV-568245'] = '120.00';
```

**I have tried this:**

```
foreach($prices as $sku => $groupAndPrice){

    $catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $catalog->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    foreach($groupAndPrice as $magentoGroupName => $itemPrice){

        $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($magentoGroupName, 'customer_group_code');

        $store_id = 0;
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
            [$productId],
            [
                'cust_group'    => $group->getId(),
                'price'         => $itemPrice
            ],
            $store_id
        );

    }
}
```

This sadly doesn't work. I have also tried $product->setGroupPrice() and I can not get that to work either. I'm using Magento 1.9.0 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to test this, but assuming you are traversing your array data correctly, this should work.

```
foreach($prices as $sku => $groupAndPrice){

$store_id = 0;
$catalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $catalog->getIdBySku($sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

foreach($groupAndPrice as $magentoGroupName => $itemPrice){

    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($magentoGroupName, 'customer_group_code');

    $product->setData('group_price',array (
        array (
            "website_id" => $store_id,
            "cust_group" => $group->getId(),
            "price" => $itemPrice
        )));

    $product->save();
}
}
```